# auto adjust screen when native.textfield is clicked using corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I'm using **corona sdk** for my project and I have a native text field in my page. When I clicked the native textfield, **the keyboard appears and the keyboard is blocking the textfield.** Is there any way beside **SCROLLVIEW** that I can use? I'm hoping that it can be like when texting, the screen auto adjust so that the textfield cannot be blocked. thanks in advance guys!

Here is my code in textfield:

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
  local group = self.view
  local bg_x = display.contentWidth
  local bg_y = display.contentHeight
  search_field = native.newTextField( 40, 85, 240, 23)
  search_field:setTextColor( 204,204,204 )
  search_field.x = bg_x*0.5
  search_field.y = bg_y*0.65
  -- search_field.size = 17
  search_field.width = bg_y*0.4
  search_field.height = bg_y*0.07
  search_field.font = native.newFont( "PTSans-Regular", 17 )
  search_field.align = "center"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to have the screen auto-adjust.  You will have to program that in yourself.  You can also do some searching on Google around the topic of 'Corona SDK textfields' and look at some of the blog and forums posts about it.  People have several different solutions to this problem but none of them will do exactly what you are looking for.

I know one solution is when the keyboard opens to create a new textfield that can be seen and as the user types it puts the text in both textfields.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/11/18/tutorial-moving-native-textfieldtextbox-objects/).

You can pan or move your whole screen by using the `transitionto` function and move your screen upwards. The only problem I would have had is knowing the right cursor or blinker position, but you could guess that by getting the Y position of your input field.

Secondly, what worked on my HTC is to add `coronaWindowMovesWhenKeyboardAppears = true` in the build Settings for Android. Alternatively, `CoronaWindowMovesWhenKeyboardAppears = true` for iOS. Notice the starting CAPS for iOS.